# Getting elements from a webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid, element

Hoping someone can help me out here.

I'm trying to pull a few bits of info from a web page programatically.

The HTML in question is like this...

```
<body>
<!-- body content -->
<div id="content">
<!-- Page Header -->
<h1>
PRODUCTNAME™
</h1>


<!-- End Page Header -->
<div id="productImg">
<img id="product.image.large.015" alt="PRODUCTNAME™" src="PRODUCTIMAGEURL" border="0" />
</div>
<div id="productAlt">
<table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr class="altRowLtGray">
<td>
Item #
<span style="text-decoration: inherit;">015</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr class="altRowLtGray">
<td>
<span style="float: left;">PRODUCTPRICE GBP</span>
<span style="float: right; padding-left: 1em;"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="altRowLtGray">
<td>
PRODUCTADDITIONALINFO
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I need to retrieve the 4 items in caps (PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTIMAGEURL, PRODUCTPRICE and PRODUCTADDITIONALINFO) but am struggling as any examples I find dont seem to be able to be transposed to suit the above HTML... but it could just be me!

I know I need to use either GetElementByID or GetElementByTagName, but i've not used either of these functions before so please forgive my ignorance.

Any help appriciated!!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you plutonix. Could you help me out with the implementation of this example? :)